# Is there an R function for finding complex numbers and counting them?

Tags: r, matrix, counter, complex-numbers, eigenvalue

I generated 1000 2x2 matrices whose elements are random numbers that range between -10 and 10.

I provided the codes I have so far.

But I'm not sure if this is the right code to find whether my list of eigenvalues are complex or not. Then for each matrix, I have to determine if the system is a stable node (both eigenvalues are real and negative); an unstable node (both eigenvalues are real and positive); a saddle (both eigenvalues are real one is positive the other negative); a stable focus (complex eigenvalues with a negative real part); an unstable focus (complex eigenvalues with a positive real part); or a center (imaginary eigenvalues, real part is zero).

I also have counters set up but not sure how to incorporate them. When I enter in the code, nothing shows up.

```
M=lapply(1:1000, function(z) matrix(runif(1000,min=-10,max=10), ncol = 2, nrow = 2))

eig=lapply(M, eigen)

V=sapply(eig, `[[`, "values")

SFcounter=0

if (is.complex(V)==T)
Re(V)>0

SFcounter=SFcounter+1
```

Comment: Why test on such a big example where you can't tell what's going on? Use `10` instead of `1000` until your code works, then scale up.

Comment: Note that `is.complex` returns a single TRUE/FALSE for the entire 'V'

Comment: You've structured your counter as if it's in a `for` loop, but you never use a `for` loop.

Comment: When I enter is.complex(V), it just shows up as true, however I know that there are some values that are not complex. I want to know how to test for each of the values.

Comment: Oh @Gregor, do you know how I can edit my codes so that it is in for loop?

Comment: What is your expected output?  Is it a counter ('SFcounter") or you want to change the `Re`.  As @Gregor mentioned, it would be easier for others to understand the issue better if the example is small and with an expected ojtput

Comment: Sorry, I'm just learning to use R so it's very confusing. But I want to determine the complex and real numbers in my list of eigenvalues (V) and then create a counter so that I can count for which pairs of eigenvalues are both real and negative (stable node), one real positive and real negative (saddle node), imaginary with real positive part (unstable focus), and etc

Comment: @akrun I'm not sure if I explained that well but please let me know if I should clarify anything

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For each `node` you have create a column in `V`. you can use the `Im` function to extract the imaginary part (whether its equal to zero or otherwise) of any complex number. You can extract the real component with `Re`. Further, if you're interested in classifying real numbers, it is all those which satisfy `Im(V) == 0` [the imaginary component is equal to zero].

If you use `apply` you can assess each eigenvalue pair in `V`, which are grouped together at each column. Based on your different classification criteria, you can identify these points using `if` statements:

```
node.classification <- function(x) {
  if ( (Im(x) == 0) && (Re(x) < 0) ) { #both eigenvalues are real and negative
    return("stable")
  } else {
    if ( (Im(x) == 0) && (Re(x) > 0) ) { #both eigenvalues are real and positive
      return("unstable")
    } else {
      if ( (Im(x) == 0) && sum((Re(x) > 0) == 1) ){ #both real one pos./one neg.
        return("saddle")
      } else {
        if ( (Im(x) != 0) && (Re(x) < 0) ) { #each complex, real part negative
          return("stable focus")
        } else {
          if ( (Im(x) != 0) && (Re(x) > 0) ) { #each complex, real part positive
            return("unstable focus")
          } else {
            return(NA)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

head(apply(V, 2, node.classification))
[1] "unstable"       "stable focus"   "stable"        
[4] "unstable"       "unstable"       "unstable focus"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know how to test if the real parts within "total" are >,<,= to 0?

Comment: To then extract the real component only, use the `Re()` function

Comment: `grepl` (and `grepl`) are vectorized, so this is a slow way to do `total = sum(grepl("[1-9]i", round(V, 1))`... though I also don't love the method `1 + 10i` will not be counted as imaginary because there is a `0` next to the `i`.

Comment: Regex is great for strings, but pretty lousy for numbers. Use OP's `V`, and `sum(Im(V) != 0)` is a great way to count values with non-zero imaginary components. No loop needed. A fair bit more work would be needed to address OP's edits about saddles, etc., but they accepted your answer already so I guess they are satisfied as-is.

Comment: Nice, good to know! Makes sense there's an `Im` function to accompany the `Re`

Comment: Wow...thank you guys!! This helps immensely. I realize that I was very off with my original coding haha

Comment: @Ang Sure thing. Good luck!!

Comment: Last question! So testing each set of eigenvalues to classify which particular node they are (stable, unstable, saddle, etc), how would I set up a working counter to keep track of each node? (since my original counter code doesn't apply since I am not using for loops)?

Comment: @Ang write a little function that takes in a pair of eigenvalues and returns the type of node. Then `apply(V, 2, your_function)`. Since you've already accepted this answer, this question should be considered closed. If you need additional help, I'd suggest asking a new question.

Comment: @Gregor Oh, got it! Thank you for the clarification! Sorry, still learning the rules here :)

Comment: @Gregor great suggestions, I've incorporated them into the correct answer.

Comment: @Ang I think this should address your latter question, sorry I missed that!

Comment: Sorry, have to downvote. Have you tested this? On input where you know the expected result?  `&&` will only work for a single case value, i.e., the first eigenvalue. Your code will disregard the second eigenvalue completely except for the one time you use `sum()`. You should have seen printed warnings about this. And the nesting is both unnecessary and ugly. `return()` will end the function as soon as it is run. The correct syntax for `if` with `else` is `if(test) { ... } else if(test2) { ... } else if(test3) {...}`. You don't put brackets immediately after the `else`.

Comment: I would recommend using `Im` and `Re` one time at the top, rather than repeatedly calling them for every condition. `xr = Re(x); xi = Im(x)`. Then your first `if` becomes `if(all(xi == 0) && all(xr < 0)) {return("stable")} else if(all(xi == 0) && xr > 0) {return("unstable")} else if ...` Though the `else`s are really unnecessary entirely since you use `return`.

Comment: i did not get these warnings you describe. moreover, the output was length 1000, so the first `return` did not end the function, or produce a vector of "stable" from the first `return` of length 1000 [see sample output]. perhaps you passed the function to `lapply` or something, rather than `apply(.,2,FUN)`, who's to say.maybe when you reproduced `V` you changed it somehow, mine was just a 2x1000 matrix.

Comment: @Dij how would I be able to extract how many are in each group ("unstable focus", "saddle", etc)

Comment: you could handle that a number of ways. one way is if you save the above list of classifications to a 1 column data frame called `df`, with a single variable called, say, `V1` , you could use the `dplyr` library and call: `df %>% group_by(V1) %>% summarise(totals = n())`